# How to create a new column with multiple values based on another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R called A.Data.

It has 8 different columns: `plate`, `row,` `col`, `TOF`, `EXT`, `green`, `red`, and `yellow`.

Below is an example of the data.

```
> head(A.Data)
    plate row col TOF EXT green red yellow 
1     1   A  12  20  21     2   0      0      
2     1   C  12  20  17     0   1      0      
3     1   C  11  20  17     0   0      1      
4     1   A  10  20  16     1   1      3      
5     1   A  10  20  16     0   0      0      
6     1   A  10  20  15     0   0      0
```

I'm trying to add a new column to `A.Data` called `conc` (short for concentration). 
The new column called `conc` depends on the value in the col column.

```
-If col is 1 or 7, conc should equal to 0
-If col is 2 or 8, conc should equal to 0.5
-If col is 3 or 9, conc should equal to 1
-If col is 4 or 10, conc should equal to 2
-If col is 5 or 11, conc should equal to 4
-If col is 6 or 12, conc should say NA
```

So for the first 6 rows of data, the `conc` column should say `NA, NA, 4, 2, 2, 2` because the `col` column values for the first 6 rows are `12, 12, 11, 10, 10, 10`.

I asked my professor for help and he gave me this hint:

`df$newcol <- rep(1, 1000)` will add a new column to the `df` data frame called `newcol` and will have 1 replicated 1000 times

Try to add a concentration column called `conc` with `0, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, NA` replicated as many times as you need for the entire column.

Here is the summary of `A.Data$col`, in case you might find it useful...

```
> summary (A.Data$col)
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12 NA's 
1128  703  538  256  156   30 2101 1039  741  294   73   60   11
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not tested, but this may work

```
map_column <- rep(c(0, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, NA),2)
df$newcol <- map_column[df$col]
```

EDIT: The idea behind this code is: `map_column`, which is a vector of length 12, serves here as a map (in the mathematical sense) between the numbers 1 to 12 and the values in the vector. For instance,

```
map_column[[1]]
```

returns the first element of the vector (0), and

```
map_column[[9]]
```

returns the 9th element of the vector (1), and so on. Now R vectors have the capability to process several inputs at once, so that

```
map_column[c(1,9)]
```

returns the corresponding elements (`c(0,1)`) at these positions in one go. Note that it is important to use a single square bracket `[` instead of `[[` here.

Comment: I'm new to using R so would you please explain why/how this works please? Thank you!

Comment: This works because the variables in df$col index into the "map_column" vector - this is a very common R trick. So, as a shorter hint, try: m = c(3, 2, 1); m[c(1,1,1,1,2)], each time you see a '1' you'll pick out the first element in m which happens to be a 3.

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
convert <- function(number){
  if(number == 1 | number == 7){return(0)}
  if(number == 2 | number == 8){return(.5)}
  if(number == 3 | number == 9){return(1)}
  if(number == 4 | number == 10){return(2)}
  if(number == 5 | number == 11){return(4)}
  if(number == 6 | number == 12){return(NA)}
}

A.Data$newcol <- do.call(rbind, lapply(A.Data$col, convert))
```

Comment: As a beginner, i like the wordiness and clarity of this answer. As I get better at thinking in R, I'll graduate to the more "elegant" solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use merge.

```
augment <- data.frame(col=1:12,conc=rep(c(0, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, NA),2))
A.Data  <-merge(A.Data,augment,by="col",sort=F)
A.Data
#   col plate row TOF EXT green red yellow conc
# 1  12     1   A  20  21     2   0      0   NA
# 2  12     1   C  20  17     0   1      0   NA
# 3  11     1   C  20  17     0   0      1    4
# 4  10     1   A  20  16     1   1      3    2
# 5  10     1   A  20  16     0   0      0    2
# 6  10     1   A  20  15     0   0      0    2
```

This creates an an augment dataframe with 2 columns, `col` corresponding to `col` in `A.Data`, and `conc` with the augment. Then merge that with A.Data based on col.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very different approach based on mathematical and logical operations:

```
x <- c(1:12, NA) # an example vector including all possible values

floor(2 ^ (z <- x %% 6 - 2)) / 2 * (z + 2 | NA)
```

The result:

```
[1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 2.0 4.0  NA 0.0 0.5 1.0 2.0 4.0  NA  NA
```

(I fear that this solution may appear like obfuscation.)